Merge Two Wav Files into one
I am recording an audio and I want to add the current longitude and latitude when the audio was recorded. I am providing text to Google text to speech to get an audio file. Audio file that is recorded is in pcm format. When I convert that pcm to wav and merge the tts wav file to recorded (converted wav file), tts wav audio behaves same but recorded wav audio distorts
ttsWavFile = FileManager(requireContext()).getWavAudioFile()

        tts.setOnUtteranceProgressListener(object : UtteranceProgressListener() {
            override fun onStart(utteranceId: String?) {
                // Optionally handle when TTS starts
            }

            override fun onDone(utteranceId: String?) {
                mergeWavFiles(ttsWavFile, recorded, finalWavFile)
            }

            override fun onError(utteranceId: String?) {
                Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Error in TTS synthesis", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show()
            }
        })

        val params = Bundle()
        params.putInt(Engine.KEY_PARAM_STREAM, android.media.AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)

        tts.synthesizeToFile(text, params, ttsWavFile, "tts1")

and here is the code to record and convert the recorded pcm audio file to wav
class AudioRecorder(
    private val context: Context,
    private val waveformView: WaveformView, private val onFileConversion: (File) -> Unit
) {

    private var audioRecord: AudioRecord? = null
    private var isRecording = false
    private var isPaused = false
    private val bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(
        44100,
        android.media.AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
        android.media.AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT
    )

    private val handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
    private var outputStream: FileOutputStream? = null
    private lateinit var audioFile: File

    fun startRecording() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                context,
                Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
            return
        }

        audioFile = FileManager(context).getPCMAudioFile()
        outputStream = FileOutputStream(audioFile)

        audioRecord = AudioRecord(
            MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,
            44100,
            android.media.AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
            android.media.AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
            bufferSize
        )

        audioRecord?.startRecording()
        isRecording = true
        isPaused = false

        Thread {
            val buffer = ByteArray(bufferSize)
            while (isRecording) {
                if (!isPaused) {
                    val read = audioRecord?.read(buffer, 0, buffer.size) ?: 0
                    if (read > 0) {
                        outputStream?.write(buffer, 0, read)
                    }
                    val amplitude = calculateRMS(buffer)
                    handler.post {
                        waveformView.updateWaveform(amplitude)
                    }
                }
            }
        }.start()
    }

    private fun calculateRMS(buffer: ByteArray): Float {
        var sum = 0f
        for (i in buffer.indices step 2) {
            val sample = ((buffer[i + 1].toInt() shl 8) or buffer[i].toInt()).toShort()
            sum += (sample * sample).toFloat()
        }
        return sqrt(sum / (buffer.size / 2))
    }

    fun pauseRecording() {
        isPaused = true
    }

    fun resumeRecording() {
        isPaused = false
    }

    fun stopRecording() {
        isRecording = false
        isPaused = false
        audioRecord?.stop()
        audioRecord?.release()
        audioRecord = null
    }

    fun saveAudio() {
        outputStream?.close()
        outputStream = null

        val pcmFile = audioFile
        val wavFile = FileManager(context).getWavAudioFile()
        val file = convertPcmToWav(pcmFile, wavFile, 44100, 2, 16)
        onFileConversion(file)

    }


    private fun convertPcmToWav(
        pcmFile: File,
        wavFile: File,
        sampleRate: Int,
        channels: Int,
        bitDepth: Int
    ): File {
        val pcmData = pcmFile.readBytes()
        val pcmSize = pcmData.size

        val wavHeader = createWavHeader(pcmSize, sampleRate, channels, bitDepth)

        FileOutputStream(wavFile).use { fos ->
            fos.write(wavHeader)
            fos.write(pcmData)
        }
        pcmFile.delete()
        return wavFile
    }

    private fun createWavHeader(
        dataSize: Int,
        sampleRate: Int,
        channels: Int,
        bitDepth: Int
    ): ByteArray {
        val totalDataLen = dataSize + 36
        val byteRate = sampleRate * channels * bitDepth / 8

        val header = ByteArray(44)

        // RIFF/WAVE header
        header[0] = 'R'.code.toByte()
        header[1] = 'I'.code.toByte()
        header[2] = 'F'.code.toByte()
        header[3] = 'F'.code.toByte()
        header[4] = (totalDataLen and 0xff).toByte()
        header[5] = ((totalDataLen shr 8) and 0xff).toByte()
        header[6] = ((totalDataLen shr 16) and 0xff).toByte()
        header[7] = ((totalDataLen shr 24) and 0xff).toByte()
        header[8] = 'W'.code.toByte()
        header[9] = 'A'.code.toByte()
        header[10] = 'V'.code.toByte()
        header[11] = 'E'.code.toByte()

        // fmt subchunk
        header[12] = 'f'.code.toByte()
        header[13] = 'm'.code.toByte()
        header[14] = 't'.code.toByte()
        header[15] = ' '.code.toByte()
        header[16] = 16 // Subchunk1 size (16 for PCM)
        header[17] = 0
        header[18] = 0
        header[19] = 0
        header[20] = 1 // Audio format (1 for PCM)
        header[21] = 0
        header[22] = channels.toByte()
        header[23] = 0
        header[24] = (sampleRate and 0xff).toByte()
        header[25] = ((sampleRate shr 8) and 0xff).toByte()
        header[26] = ((sampleRate shr 16) and 0xff).toByte()
        header[27] = ((sampleRate shr 24) and 0xff).toByte()
        header[28] = (byteRate and 0xff).toByte()
        header[29] = ((byteRate shr 8) and 0xff).toByte()
        header[30] = ((byteRate shr 16) and 0xff).toByte()
        header[31] = ((byteRate shr 24) and 0xff).toByte()
        header[32] = (channels * bitDepth / 8).toByte() // Block align
        header[33] = 0
        header[34] = bitDepth.toByte()
        header[35] = 0

        // data subchunk
        header[36] = 'd'.code.toByte()
        header[37] = 'a'.code.toByte()
        header[38] = 't'.code.toByte()
        header[39] = 'a'.code.toByte()
        header[40] = (dataSize and 0xff).toByte()
        header[41] = ((dataSize shr 8) and 0xff).toByte()
        header[42] = ((dataSize shr 16) and 0xff).toByte()
        header[43] = ((dataSize shr 24) and 0xff).toByte()

        return header
    }


}

now when I try to merge these two audios, i am facing an issue that first audio that is textToSpeech audio is being merged fine but the second recorded audio is being distorted. below is the code merge two wavs
fun mergeWavFiles(wavFile1: File, wavFile2: File, outputFile: File) {

        try {
            // Open input streams for both WAV files
            val inputStream1 = FileInputStream(wavFile1)
            val inputStream2 = FileInputStream(wavFile2)

            // Create output stream for the merged WAV file
            val outputStream = FileOutputStream(outputFile)

            // Read the headers of the input files
            val header1 = ByteArray(44)
            val header2 = ByteArray(44)
            inputStream1.read(header1)
            inputStream2.read(header2)

            // Write the header from the first file to the output
            outputStream.write(header1)

            // Read audio data from both files and combine them
            val buffer = ByteArray(1024)
            var bytesRead: Int

            // Read the first file after the header and write to the output
            while (inputStream1.read(buffer).also { bytesRead = it } != -1) {
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead)
            }

            // Read the second file after the header and write to the output
            while (inputStream2.read(buffer).also { bytesRead = it } != -1) {
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead)
            }

            // Close all streams
            inputStream1.close()
            inputStream2.close()
            outputStream.close()

            // Update the WAV header for the new file
            updateWavHeader(outputFile)

            wavFile1.delete()
            wavFile2.delete()
            dialog.dismiss()


        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            println("Error merging WAV files: ${e.message}")
        }
    }


    fun checkWavProperties(wavFile: File): Triple<Int, Int, Int>? {
        try {
            FileInputStream(wavFile).use { fis ->
                val header = ByteArray(44)
                fis.read(header)

                val sampleRate = ((header[27].toInt() and 0xFF shl 24) or
                        (header[26].toInt() and 0xFF shl 16) or
                        (header[25].toInt() and 0xFF shl 8) or
                        (header[24].toInt() and 0xFF))

                val channels = (header[23].toInt() and 0xFF shl 8) or (header[22].toInt() and 0xFF)
                val bitDepth = (header[35].toInt() and 0xFF shl 8) or (header[34].toInt() and 0xFF)

                return Triple(sampleRate, channels, bitDepth)
            }
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        return null
    }


    // Function to update WAV header with the correct size information
    fun updateWavHeader(wavFile: File) {
        try {
            val fileAccess = RandomAccessFile(wavFile, "rw")

            val fileSize = fileAccess.length()
            val dataSize = fileSize - 44

            // Update ChunkSize (file size - 8) at offset 4
            fileAccess.seek(4)
            fileAccess.write(intToLittleEndian((fileSize - 8).toInt()))

            // Update Subchunk2Size (data size) at offset 40
            fileAccess.seek(40)
            fileAccess.write(intToLittleEndian(dataSize.toInt()))

            fileAccess.close()
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }

    // Helper function to convert an integer to little-endian byte array
    fun intToLittleEndian(value: Int): ByteArray {
        return byteArrayOf(
            (value and 0xff).toByte(),
            ((value shr 8) and 0xff).toByte(),
            ((value shr 16) and 0xff).toByte(),
            ((value shr 24) and 0xff).toByte()
        )
    }


There are lots of magic numbers used in the code, making it difficult to understand.    Could you please replace the numbers with variables?
I couldn't get the issue here, however for debugging purposes I would probably try tweaking the values here:
AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(
44100,
android.media.AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
android.media.AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT
)

I could have tried MP3 or any other formats but they are requiring API level 28 however my current minimum is 24

and the issue here is while conversion of pcm to wav and then merging it with another wav. First wav is behaving fine but second wav sound is distorted (second wav sound is the one that was converted to wav
